# Android Applications Development without device

Tags: java, android

This question might be silly...but still:
I would like to learn the Android SDK, now I dont have an Android based phone,Can I still develop for it even if I dont own an android phone?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  The Android SDK comes with an emulator, so you can run your apps on that.

Answer (score 2):

Get Eclipse and Download the Android SDK through eclipse. This will allow you to debug your apps on the emulator right from your IDE. Also allows for Android App projects and code highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There is an (essentially) fully functional emulator.